# Where does "amen" come from?

Tags: prayer, terminology

Watched a video on YouTube. My first mistake. They were talking about the word "amen" coming from a Roman god Amen-Ra, I think. I thought "amen" just meant "to agree". How do people research this stuff to come up with what "amen" means anyway.

Comment: Wikipedia does a good job of answering this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amen#Etymology

Comment: -1 for lack of research effort. You should not get all information on Youtube. Youtube may help provide the basic introduction, but validation and verifiability are also important.

Comment: Even if it did come from an Egyptian pagan culture, would that be important? It almost certainly had a completely secular meaning by the time it was used in the written text. Would there be other serious ramifications of any particular etymology?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the English language.

Comment: Glad I asked the question. I just really wanted to know dose it mean "I agree" that's all. And this is my research effort not YouTube.

Comment: It was not a Roman God, but an Egyptian God which caused the confusion.  Next you'll ask about the "son" of God vs the "sun" God - only in English are they the same.  'filius' is not easy to confuse with 'sol'.  Most of those YouTube video are junk - as are the ones about Freemasons :D (insert plug here)

Answer (score 2):

The use of the "Amen" comes from the last word of the most used Bible Translations.

The word itself in the original Greek is Amēn Ἀμήν⧽ Amen from the Hebrew which means "true".

The following is a quote from Smith's Bible dictionary.

> A'men. Literally "true" and used as a substantive, "that which is true",. "truth", Isa_65:16, a word used in strong asseverations, fixing, as it were, the stamp of truth upon the assertion which it accompanied, and making it binding as an oath. Compare Num_5:22.
>
> In the synagogues and private houses, it was customary for the people or members of the family who were present to say "Amen" to the prayers which were offered. Mat_6:13; 1Co_14:16. And not only public prayers, but those offered in private, and doxologies, were appropriately concluded with "Amen". Rom_9:5; Rom_11:36; Rom_15:33; Rom_16:27;
> 2Co_13:14; etc.

When Christianity spread the use of saying A'men was used in the same way as a way of validating the word as the word of God, and is still used in The Baptist church as a way of affirming what was said as being true.

Answer (score 2):

The mere fact that this youtuber thought Amen-Ra was a Roman God speaks greatly about the quality of his videos. Some unbelievers seem to see a pagan behind everything a Christian does.

> Old English, from ecclesiastical Latin, from Greek amēn, from Hebrew
>   'āmēn ‘truth, certainty’, used adverbially as expression of agreement,
>   and adopted in the Septuagint as a solemn expression of belief or
>   affirmation.

Answer (score 1):

*Amen is a derivative from the Hebrew verb aman "to strengthen" or "Confirm".*

> The word Amen is one of a small number of Hebrew words which have been
>   imported unchanged into the liturgy of the Church, propter sanctiorem
>   as St. Augustine expresses it, in virtue of an exceptionally sacred
>   example. "So frequent was this Hebrew in the mouth of Our Saviour",
>   observes the Catechism of the Council of Trent, "that it pleased the
>   Holy Ghost to have it perpetuated in the Church of God". In point of
>   fact St. Matthew attributes it to Our Lord twenty-eight times, and St.
>   John in its doubled form twenty-six times. As regards the etymology,
>   Amen is a derivative from the Hebrew verb aman "to strengthen" or
>   "Confirm". - Cf. [Amen | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01407b.htm).

And

AMEN *("So is it," or "So shall it be")*

> A word used at the conclusion of a prayer, or in other connections, to
>   express affirmation, approval, or desire. **It is derived from the Old
>   Testament Hebrew**, and is perhaps the most widely known word in human
>   speech; being familiar to Jews, Christians, and Mohammedans. It occurs
>   thirteen times in the Masoretic text of the Old Testament, and in the
>   Septuagint in three additional passages (Jer. iii. 19, xv. 11, Isa.
>   xxv. 1). From these passages it is possible to trace in part the
>   gradual development of Amen from an adjective (or, according to Barth,
>   "Die Nominalbildung in den Semitischen Sprachen," 5c, 7b, a noun,
>   meaning **"firmness," "certainty"**) into an indeclinable
>   interjection. - Cf. [AMEN | JewishEncyclopedia.com](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/1383-amen).